# How can i convert an oval to circle openGL ES2.0 Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have been working on an openGL ES 2.0 Android project. My objective is to create a circle. From the help that i got from online, i managed to run this code which is suppose to give a circle in the view,but instead i got an oval. I tried many ways to make it circle. Any help shal appreciated

Thanks

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.util.Log;

public class Circle {

private int mProgram, mPositionHandle, mColorHandle, mMVPMatrixHandle;
private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
private float vertices[] = new float[364 * 3];
float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };

private final String vertexShaderCode = "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;"
        + "attribute vec4 vPosition;" + "void main() {"
        + "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" + "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode = "precision mediump float;"
        + "uniform vec4 vColor;" + "void main() {"
        + "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" + "}";

Circle() {
    vertices[0] = 0;
    vertices[1] = 0;
    vertices[2] = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 364; i++) {
        vertices[(i * 3) + 0] = (float) (0.5 * Math.cos((3.14 / 180)
                * (float) i) + vertices[0]);
        vertices[(i * 3) + 1] = (float) (0.5 * Math.sin((3.14 / 180)
                * (float) i) + vertices[1]);
        vertices[(i * 3) + 2] = 0;
    }

    Log.v("Thread", "" + vertices[0] + "," + vertices[1] + ","
            + vertices[2]);
    ByteBuffer vertexByteBuffer = ByteBuffer
            .allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vertexByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mVertexBuffer = vertexByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    mVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    mVertexBuffer.position(0);
    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram(); // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader); // add the vertex shader
                                                    // to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment
                                                        // shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {

    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
    return shader;
}

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false, 12, mVertexBuffer);

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 364);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

}

}
```

And the output i am getting is this

[image]

Comment: The answer lies with your projection-view matrix, probably something with the screen aspect ratio. Remember, as the screen is rotated, the aspect ratio of the screen changes as well. Brush up on your math and you'll fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertex coordinates span a (normalised) range of -1 to +1 - And it appears you are generating vertices from -0.5 to +0.5.

Now, where does the GL engine draw ? To a buffer that is provided by a window system - in this case the Android window system. The Android window system (ie, the linux kernel display driver in the lowest level) provides a buffer that has a widthxheight of say 480x640 (your screenshot shows that width < height). So, the drawn circle on the screen has a width of 0.5*480, but height of 0.5*640, hence it gives an oval shape.

You will have to scale down your y coordinate by the ratio of (screenwidth/screenheight), to get a true circle. You can get it using either egl API or Android API in your application.